# connecting to a network using route command

Tags: windows, networking, subnet, route

I have a computer with an external IP(192.168.223.220) and also an internal address (10.1.1.20) in order to connect to some servers that don't have external addresses only 10.1.1.xx . in order to connect to these servers from other machines I used the following command "route ADD 10.1.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.223.220" 
and than I was able to connect to the servers using there 10.1.1.xx address.

The problem is that the hard disk of main server(192.168.223.220) died and was replaced and after the that I am not able to connect to the servers as before, the route command succeeds and I can ping 10.1.1.20 but not the other servers.

Thanks

I am using Windows XP and the print outs are

Interface configuration:

```
D:\AurosHome\Scripts>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : N100-master
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration #2
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-30-48-34-BA-B9
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.225.180
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.225.254
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.225.2

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-30-48-34-BA-B8
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.20
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Mellanox IPoIB Adapter
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-02-C9-25-34-0D
```

Routing table

```
D:\AurosHome\Scripts>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 30 48 34 ba b9 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration #2 - Packet Sche
duler Miniport
0x3 ...00 30 48 34 ba b8 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration - Packet Schedul
er Miniport
0x10005 ...00 02 c9 25 34 0d ...... Mellanox IPoIB Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.225.254  192.168.225.180      10
         10.1.1.0    255.255.255.0        10.1.1.20       10.1.1.20       10
        10.1.1.20  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10
    10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        10.1.1.20       10.1.1.20       10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
    192.168.225.0    255.255.255.0  192.168.225.180  192.168.225.180      10
    192.168.225.180  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10
    192.168.225.255  255.255.255.255  192.168.225.180  192.168.225.180      10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0        10.1.1.20       10.1.1.20       10

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0  192.168.225.180  192.168.225.180      10
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        10.1.1.20       10.1.1.20       1
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        10.1.1.20           10005       1
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255  192.168.225.180  192.168.225.180      1

Default Gateway:   192.168.225.254
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Please post the full results of the following two commands: "ipconfig /all" and "route print" and confirm what operating systems you're dealing with.

Comment: Have you used Internet Connection Sharing or Network Bridge to achieve this? Windows does not route different subnets in it's Standard configuration.

Comment: Based on the routing table in your question, I can see that your company is in serious need of someone to manage corporate networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling Windows as Router:

In the registry:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControllSet\Service\Tcpip\Parameters

Add :

> IPEnableRouter
>
> REG_DWORD
>   Value: 1

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but after rebooting I couldn't connect to the main server using RDP. any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You have no persistent routes configured on your system, which means any you created were lost on a reboot. The only ones showing are dynamically added by Windows.

Try adding your routes again but add "-p" to the end of the command.